# How to monitor other apps network usage?

Tags: android, android-trafficstats

I use `TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes` to get network usage. It works fine for my app but for other apps always returns -1 (UNSUPPORTED). How can i get network usage for other apps without root permission?

Comment: Use app monitoring apps...

Comment: @B001 I need to add this feature to my application.

Comment: But why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @B001 I am developing a network info app.

Comment: @amirrezash please check my answer. If it answers your question, mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since android 7, you can query only your own app traffic usage. From  `TraffixStats.getUidRxBytes` docs:

> Starting in `N` this will only report traffic statistics for the calling UID. **It will return UNSUPPORTED for all other UIDs for privacy reasons.** To access historical network statistics belonging to other UIDs, use `NetworkStatsManager`.

Going to `NetworkStatsManager`, you could use `queryDetailsForUid`, but as documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html) says:

> NOTE: Calling `querySummaryForDevice(int, String, long, long)` **or accessing stats for apps other than the calling app** requires the permission `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`, which is a **system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps.** However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and **the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application**.

So be warned that the user must give some special permission to your app.

**Edit:**

I used once `UsageStatsManager`, I think it's what you are looking for: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#queryUsageStats(int,%20long,%20long)